# .NET Core development with VS 2012?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Can I develop .NET Core projects with VS 2012 or do I need VS 2015+? What are the system requirements or components needed?

Comment: Google It mate ! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/windows-prerequisites

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you can't. You need VS 2015 + Update 3.

> .NET Core development on Windows with Visual Studio requires:
>
> - Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.3 or later
> - NuGet Manager extension for Visual Studio
> - .NET Core Tooling Preview 2

~ [.NET Prereqs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/windows-prerequisites)

Comment: Check this all the necessary information listed here :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/